# javascript switch statement not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
        var input = $('#csearchtext').val();
    var dropdownindex = $("select[name='columnlist'] option:selected").index();
    var radioselected = $("input:radio[name='group2']:checked").val();
    var searchpattern = '';

    switch (radioselected) {
        case 1:
            searchpattern = '/^'+input+'/'+'ig';
            break;
        case 2:
            searchpattern = input;
            break;
        case 3:
            searchpattern = '/'+input+'$/'+'ig';
            break;
    }


    console.log(searchpattern);

    $('#table_id').dataTable().fnFilter(searchpattern, dropdownindex + 1, false, true, true, false);
```

Input is working fine, as-well as dropdown and radio selecting. Radioselected is either 1,2, or 3 and 2 is the default checked, though with the console.log searchpattern is still empty yet the switch statement should go into effect every time.

Comment: What does `console.log(radioselected)` show?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`val` always returns a string or `undefined`. `switch` works with strict equality (e.g., the same as `===`, not `==`), so either use `parseInt` on `radioselected` or use `"1"` and such as the cases.

[Gratuitous live example](http://jsbin.com/ugimimu/1) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ugimimu/1/edit)